# Android device mounted as gphoto2 rather than mtp

Tags: mount, android, mtp

I have two computers running Ubuntu 14.04 fully updated (apt-get dist-upgrade). On one my android phone mounts in Nautilus automatically using an mtp:// location, which works fairly well. On the other it mounts as a gphoto2:// location, which doesn't work well at all well. If I press CTRL+L and manually enter the mtp:// address it works perfectly.

Can anyone suggest a way to stop my computer using gphoto, and always use mtp, at least for this device?